# Is there a way for a member function to know if the object is an rvalue or lvalue?

Tags: c++, c++14

My usecase is I have a class X which has a member function that returns a modified copy of X. Some of these member functions might be stacked like this

```
X X_before{init};
X X_after = X_before.op_1().op_2().op_3();
```

In the above code op_1 would create a copy. Now what I am thinking is that there's really no reason why op_2 and op_3 should also need to create a new copy, since `X_before.op_1()` is now an rvalue. Is there a way that I could achieve this in current C++? I am using C++14, but would also be interested to know if this is possible in later versions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since C++11 we have [ref-qualified member functions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/member_functions#ref-qualified_member_functions), with that overload resolution could select the appropriate overloading based on the object to be called on is lvalue or rvalue.

> ```
> #include <iostream>
> struct S {
>     void f() & { std::cout << "lvalue\n"; }
>     void f() &&{ std::cout << "rvalue\n"; }
> };
>  
> int main(){
>     S s;
>     s.f();            // prints "lvalue"
>     std::move(s).f(); // prints "rvalue"
>     S().f();          // prints "rvalue"
> }
> ```